# Unable to mount volumes to docker-machine from ubuntu 18.04 host

Tags: docker, virtualbox, mount, docker-machine

I am trying to Dockerize the React application on Ubuntu 18.04 host to node 12 guest. I am following this guide https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/ and everything works fine until I get to mounting volumes to the docker-machine. After mounting the volume the target folder on guest is empty or even removes the existing files already mounted in the image.

Following is my Dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache git

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.0.1 -g --silent

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

create a docker-machine and configure shell to connect to it :

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox lz-front
eval $(docker-machine env lz-front)
```

Mount the project root-folder

```
sanka@ThinkPad-P1:~/code/lz/lz-new$ VBoxManage sharedfolder add lz-front --name lz-new --hostpath /home/sanka/code/lz/lz-new/ --automount
```

Build the image

```
sanka@ThinkPad-P1:~/code/lz/lz-new$ docker build -t lz:dev .
```

Inspecting what is inside reveals all is as expected:

```
sanka@ThinkPad-P1:~/code/lz/lz-new$ docker run -it --rm lz:dev sh
/app # ls
node_modules       package-lock.json  package.json
/app #
```

But after mounting volumes the target folder contains just node_modules

```
sanka@ThinkPad-P1:~/code/lz/lz-new$ docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -v /app/node_modules -p 3001:3000 -it --rm lz:dev sh
/app # ls
node_modules
/app #
```

If I run the run command outside of the docker-machine the application starts up normally. So I am suspecting VirtualBox auto-mount doesn't work for me.

**EDIT:**
this shows the content of the working directory

```
sanka@ThinkPad-P1:~/code/lz/lz-new$ ls
config-overrides.js  Dockerfile    package.json  README.md  test
docker-compose.yml   node_modules  public        src
```

**EDIT 2:**
after logging into docker-machine with ssh I can validate that the auto-mounting shared folder works as they are present in the VM

```
sanka@ThinkPad-P1:~/code/lz/lz-new$ docker-machine ssh lz-front
docker@lz-front:~$ ls /
bin       home      lib       lz-new    proc      sbin      usr
dev       hosthome  lib64     mnt       root      sys       var
etc       init      linuxrc   opt       run       tmp
```

Comment: The `-v ${PWD}:/app` you are passing to `docker run` effectively maps the working directory on your host machine to the app folder inside the container. Any contents in the app folder will effectively be masked by this. If you can clarify what you are trying to achieve with the volume mapping, I may be able to suggest an alternate way of running the container.

Comment: Also not sure what you are doing with `-v /app/node_modules`. According to the documentation the -v option is followed by either a single value for a named-volume or something of the format `host-folder:container-folder`

Comment: I am trying to get the hot-reloading on development server to get closer to the final production environment. In order to get the reloading working I  want to enable polling via chockaddir. However for now I can't  even spin up the image on the machine

Comment: I edited the question to show the contents of the working directory. So /app on the  guest machine should not be empty. Regarding the `-v /app/node_modules` removing it doesnt help and as the guide states: its there to ensure to use container version of node_modules

Comment: I could not reproduce this on Ubuntu machine (not virtualbox). The `-v ${PWD}:/app` causes the host-folder to be mounted to `/app` inside the container and if I login to a shell in the container and run `ls` I can see the contents of the host folder in that folder.
The `-v /app/node_modules` is interesting in that it creates a volume and binds it to the `/app/node_modules` folder inside the container. Running `docker inspect` on the container revealed this to me. You may want to run the same and see what it shows you

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you see shared folders inside the docker-machine under the /media foldler ?

Comment: I'm not running a docker-machine but I was able to confirm that `-v /app/node_modules` is good. As you mentioned this is done to effectively NOT map the node_modules from host folder and instead keep the node_modules which you installed inside your image at build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the VBoxManage command to:

```
sanka@ThinkPad-P1:~/code/lz/lz-new$ VBoxManage sharedfolder add lz-front --name ${PWD} --hostpath ${PWD} --automount
```

solves the issue. My best guess is that volumes are mounted from the VM users folder rather then from host folder directly. This folder is empty at the time of executing docker run. Mounting the directory to required place into the VM prior to executing docker run enables proper mounting.